# Offsets in op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]
Why is the following calculation wrong? I mean, I know it is I am simply not sure why.

Let \$V_x\$ denote the voltage between the ground and the 1K resistor.

Then, for \$V_{OS}=4mV\$:

\$V_{OS}/R_1=(V_x-V_{OS})/R_2\$

And

\$(V_o-V_x)/R_3-V_x/1K=V_{OS}/R_1\$

Comment: Label your resistors first (R1, R2, etc) and then figure out which one you're referring to when you write something like "4mV/1M". I don't know which 1M you're thinking should have 4mV across it ...

Comment: The equations are a mess.

Comment: @Chu better now?

Comment: *Let Vx denote the voltage between the ground and the 1K resistor.* What a confusing sentence. Either Vx is the voltage across Rx or just indicate Vx in the schematic.

Comment: Yes, better. See answer.

Comment: @peripatein Your equation are correct http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.004%2F1000+%3D+(x+-+0.004)%2F1000;+(O+-+x)%2F1000+-+x%2F1+%3D%3D+0.004%2F1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ5EB3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage at point \$V_X\$ is equal to

$$V_X = V_{OS}*\left(1+ \frac{R2}{R1}\right) = 4mV*2 = 8mV$$

Therefore \$I_4 = I_2+I_3\$ --->\$I_2 = \frac{V_{OS}}{R1} = 4nA \$ and \$I_3 = \frac{V_X}{R_3} = 8 \mu A\$

So, the \$V_O\$ is equal to:

$$V_O = Vx + I_4*R_4 = 8.012V $$

And the nodal equation should look like this:

$$\frac{V_{OS}}{R_1}+\frac{V_{OS}-V_X}{R_2} = 0 $$

$$\frac{V_X-V_{OS}}{R_2}+\frac{V_X}{R_3}+\frac{V_X-V_0}{R_4}=0$$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.004%2F1000+%2B+(0.004+-+x)%2F1000+%3D+0;+(x+-+0.004)%2F1000+%2B+x%2F1+%2B+(x+-+O)%2F1000+%3D+0

Comment: does it make sense that due to Vos=4mV, the dc voltage offset at the output would be as high as 8V?

Comment: But this is how it is. DC output voltage is very large due to large DC gain (2000)

Comment: now I am asked to determine the output offset when the input ac is coupled through a capacitor C, and when, instead, a large capacitor is placed in series
with 1K resistor.

Comment: The capacitor at DC act like an open circuit hence you can remove R1 and solver for Vo and for the last case remove 1k resistor and solve for Vo.

Comment: Why was it important to add that the capacitor is large?

Comment: Large capacitor will start acting as "short circuit" early for AC signal (lower frequency). For example if R = 1kΩ and 10µF we can ignore the cap for F > 0.16/(R*C) = 16Hz

Answer (score 1):

This does not need that complex equations. Assuming the input current of the opamp to be zero or at least causing no remarkable voltage to 1MOhm when compared to 4mV, one should (NOTE1) see:

The feedback network attenuates the output about to 1/1000 th part if the input (the leftmost terminal) is unconnected.The attenuation is about to 1/2000 th if the input is connected to 0V.

Thus the output voltage is 4V if the input is not connected and 8V if the input is connected to 0V

NOTE1: The voltage divider has Thevenin resistance about 999 Ohms. The 1 to 2 MOhm loading causes much less voltage drop than usual resistor tolerances cause uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

For nodal analysis it's better to stick with the convention: sum of currents away from a node =0.

Thus, assuming the input signal (not identified) is zero, and the 1k is \$\small R_4\$, and the output voltage is \$\small V_O\$:

$$\frac{V_{OS}}{R_1}+\frac{V_{OS}-V_x}{R_2}=0$$

and

$$\frac{V_{x}-V_{OS}}{R_2}+\frac{V_x}{R_4}+\frac{V_x-V_O}{R_3}=0$$

Remove \$\small V_x\$ from the simultaneous equations to find \$\small V_O\$